# React How to get information from Get statement

Tags: node.js, reactjs, get

Hello I'm building a pokedex and now I'm trying to get the pokemon information that was clicked. 
so I get the URl

`http://localhost:3000/#/pokemon/Bulbasaur`

an trying to recor the Bulbasur information to display it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pokemons from '../pokemon/pokedex.json';



class PokePath extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


render() {
    const {id, num, name} = this.state
    return (
        <div className="row">        
                <div className="col">
                   <h1>{Pokemons[this.props.id-1].name}</h1>
                </div> 
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default PokePath;
```

This where I'm getting the data:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "num": "001",
  "name": "Bulbasaur",
  "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
  "type": [
    "Grass",
    "Poison"
  ],
```

]

In order to get to the bulbasaur page I did this:

```
                                return (
        <div className = "row">{Pokemons.map((postDetail, id) => {
            return(             
                <div className = "col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-5">
                    <StyledLink to={`pokemon/${postDetail.name}`}>  
                        <div className = "card">
                            <div className = "card-header">
                            <div>
                                <a key={id}>{postDetail.id}</a>
                                    </div>
                                        <div className="text-center">
                                            <img src={postDetail.img} alt="new"/>
                                        </div>
                                    <div className="text-center">
                                        <a key={id}>{postDetail.name}</a>
                                    </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </StyledLink>   
                </div>); 
             })}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: If you are trying to get response from any api just use axios.get i.e axios.get( url, payload);

Comment: Is not from an Api is from a json file

Comment: Can you paste the full code? I can not see the list of pokemons on which user will click and see the information.

Comment: Ok I add the section where bulbasaur information is

Comment: what Id you are passing did you console log your id?

Comment: I upload to see how I get to the bulbasaur page...I use .map (hopefully it respond to your question)

Comment: Can you please share the full code Its getting more confusing to me now :-O or just post your twitter here. So that we can get it resolved.

Comment: What is StyledLink and why pass name of the pokemon when using id in the component?